# Syntax issue with multiple Mysql queries

Tags: mysql, syntax, foreign-keys

I have a basic Mysql syntax question. The function below returns a Mysql foreign key constraint failure error:

```
public function delete($table, $where)
    {
        return 'DELETE FROM '.$this->escape_table($table).' WHERE '.implode(' ', $where);
    }
```

I would like to add

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
```

before the delete statement and

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

after it, so that the function disables foreign key checks, executes the delete query and re-enables foreign key checks. I can't seem to get the syntax quite right. Anyone willing to help me out?

Comment: Not all db drivers support multi-command queries. What language and db library/version are you using?

Comment: You have to rewrite it so that it uses multiple queries,show more code.

Comment: The above code is part of this PHP-file (starting at line 39): https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/91295308/

It's an older version of Kohana which started returning this error after upgrading to PHP 5.4. Everything seems to be working fine apart from this issue.